# В PyCharm джанго. При импорте приложений подсвечивается красным

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Модули приложений, почему-то подсвечиваются красным, но при этом сам проект запускается нормально без ошибок. Подсвечиваются только модули приложений, модули джанго не подсвечиваются, как на скриншоте ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думал, что проблема в настройках интерпретатора в джанго, но всё вроде настроено нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В INSTALLED_APPS мое приложение имеет имя `MiniBlog`, так же я пробовал менять его на `MiniBlog.apps.MiniblogConfig`

В фале apps.py ничего не менял:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MiniblogConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'MiniBlog'
```

Заметил, что при убирании имени модуля приложения перестаёт подсвечиваться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но что если придется импортировать модели из других приложений? выглядеть это будет как

```
from MiniBlog.models import Post, Likes
from Chat.models import Chat
```

И тогда две эти строчки будут подсвечиваться красным хоть и работать

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рад если вы поможете мне решить эту проблему.

Comment: Ну подсвечивается, а запускается хотя-бы?

Comment: Покажите структуру проекта

Comment: Проект работает. Меня просто раздражает, что они горят красным цветом, ощущения как-будто я делаю, что-то не правильное. Надеялся, что у кого-то была схожая проблема и он смог ее решить.